# SQL to Django Translation

Tags: mysql, django, django-queryset

This statement works in SQL, I just cannot figure out how to convert it to django. Im sure it uses prefetch_related, Prefetch, or select_related but im still having a hard time understanding those concepts.  I do see that prefetch basically has to have the field under that table.

My goal: Not all brands have products. All products have brands. Show my only brands with products. I was hoping to implement `Brand.objects.[insert-filter-here]`

Model.py (appended version of actual models.py file)

```
class Product(models.Model):
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand)

class Brand(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField
```

SQL

```
SELECT DISTINCT products_brand.name FROM produts_brand INNER JOIN products_product on products_brand.id=products_product.brand_id;
```

Its 2 tables becuase the products table has many many columns (27), I guess the other option is to just
combine them. But I wanted more control over Brand objects for ease of lookup/editing.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: https://multitasked.net/2010/07/08/082300.html
There is one option, I think there is a better way to do a join though. Still looking

Answer (score 1):

It should just be `Brand.objects.filter(product__isnull=False).distinct()`. You can follow the foreign key relation backwards using the default reverse name (or a different one if you used the `related_query_name` field argument to specify one when declaring your `ForeignKeyField`).

Without the `distinct()` you may get duplicate entries.

See the ["Lookups that span relationships"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) docs for more details and examples.

Comment: You're missing `.distinct('name')`.

Comment: and tack on a `.distinct()` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#distinct

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys! I failed to mention i was using MYSQL backend and not SQLite but Peters answer got me in the right direction though, I got.

`Brand.objects.values('name').distinct().filter(products__isnull=False)`